# Eclipse 3.7 M6 versus team share menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I downloaded Eclipse Indigo (3.7) M6, the 'classic' edition. I added subversive and egit.

Still, the team menu contains only 'apply patch'. No 'share'. Yes, I have restarted.

I can't find anything in the way of a setting that seems likely to have any effect.

Answer (score 2):

1) you can restart with **eclipse -clean** to rebuild the extension registry cache (that should get updated when you add new plugins)

2) Check your Help>About>Installation details.  Did the 2 SCMs install?  Can you go to Window>Open Perspective>Other... and open the Git Repository Exploring perspective?

3) Check your error log ... has anything gone bad? http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: Early indications is that it was stuff in .settings left over from Helios.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same kind of problem (with subversion). My solution : Launch the old version of eclipse, use disconnect in the team menu, and relaunch the new version.